# PGF/TikZ externalization on ubuntu does not generate a separate PDF-file

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, ubuntu, tikz-external, externalize

I am trying to compile my document on my ubuntu 18.04 system with TikZ's externalization enabled, but it won't generate separate PDFs for the figures. Interestingly, it works smoothing on my Windows system. I am using texstudio (2.12.6 @ ubuntu) calling

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz_external_figs/]

\begin{document}
    This is a test document.

    \begin{figure}
        \tikzexternalenable
        \tikzsetnextfilename{testtikzenableMax} %% set filename tikz externalize
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[->] (0,0) -- (10,2);
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The process ended normal. So, I searched the whole system but were unable to find a *testtikzenableMax.pdf* file, nor an .md5 or .dvi file. The bug is killing me as I ran out of ideas nor do I understand, why this should be a system-dependent behavior.

Log-file: [TEST.log](https://pastebin.com/FGPHQ03B)

UPDATE: TeX Live 2019 (including *pdftex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20*) [log-file](https://pastebin.com/1ExJPVnw)

Comment: Can you please show us your log file? You can take help of sites like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Niranjan, thx nice little website. I uploaded the log-file and added a link in the post above

Comment: You are trying to find a file with name `testtikzenableMax.pdf`, but your log says (on line 517) that output is written on `TEST.pdf`. I suggest you to check the directory (in which you have saved the `.tex` file) if you find any output file with name `TEST.pdf`.

Comment: Also one important point, LaTeX always generates output files with the same filenames as of the source files.

Comment: You seem to have a very old TeX installation. Does updating it help? You may also want to load `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

Comment: @Niranjan the command `\tikzsetnextfilename{testtikzenableMax}` let tikz-externalize use this name for the next figure. Generating the main file (here TEST.tex) is not the problem

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat the TeX version is texlive-latex-recommended 2017.20180305-1. This seems to be the newest version

Comment: You have `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)`, I have `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)`. While I do not know what recommended means in this context, I am wondering if you are using a two years old installation, and whether updating your installation solves the issue.

Comment: `texlive-latex-recommended` is the ubuntu package how to install TeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245982/differences-between-texlive-packages-in-linux). Therefore, 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 is the recommended version for ubuntu 18.04. Nevertheless, I'll check the version on my windows system

Comment: I think there is some misinterpretation. The packages get constantly updated, and errors get fixed. You may very well suffering from a bug that got fixed some time ago.

Comment: I updated the TeX Live to 2019 (see log: https://pastebin.com/1ExJPVnw) it still won't generate separate PDFs for the figure(s)