# tlmgr won't update

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I have texlive (version 2023) on Linux Mint. When I try to install a package using `tlmgr install sidecap`  it says I need to update tlmgr first. I used `tlmgr update --self` but that returns:

```
Unable to download the checksum of the remote TeX Live database,
but found a local copy, so using that.

You may want to try specifying an explicit or different CTAN mirror,
or maybe you need to specify proxy information if you're behind a firewall;
see the information and examples for the -repository option at
https://tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html
(and in the output of install-tl --help).

tlmgr: package repository https://mirror.niser.ac.in/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: unknown)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] update: texlive.infra [345k] (66512 -> 66822) ... TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (download_file failed) for https://mirror.niser.ac.in/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/texlive.infra.tar.xz
tlmgr: Installation of new version of texlive.infra failed, trying to unwind.
tlmgr: Restoring of old package did NOT succeed.
tlmgr: Error message from unpack: don't know how to unpack
tlmgr: Most likely repair: run tlmgr install texlive.infra and hope.
done
tlmgr: The file README has disappeared from the critical package texlive.infra but is still present in dehyph:texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph/README dvipdfmx:texmf-dist/fonts/cmap/dvipdfmx/README mfware:texmf-dist/mft/base/README texlive-scripts:texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/tetex/README
tlmgr: action update returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: package log updated: /home/fes33/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Reading some of the other queries I gathered that it's because the mirror niser.ac.in/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet isn't working. I tried the solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578950/284249) but it didn't work:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
```

What else can I do?

Comment: Neither log appears to be from an upstream installation from https://tug.org/texlive/ how have you installed TeX Live? I'm not certain but sounds like the first is a local TinyTeX installation (via R?) and the second (on sudo path) is an `apt`-installed. If you installed from the OS package manager that is how you should update TeX Live, OS-packaged TL distros generally aren't capable of allowing finer-grained management of the TL distribution through `tlmgr`. They also separate the full TeX Live into a few different apt-packages (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504566/106162).

Comment: Yes, I've been using R Markdown and Quarto and use it to render pdf. I also installed Tex Studio so I think the other one comes from that.

Comment: OK, installing TeXStudio via the OS package manager has installed another distro as a dependency, this one comes up first in the super user's PATH while the TinyTeX is first in your own PATH. Did you try running `tlmgr install texlive.infra` as the first error message suggests?

Comment: Can you try updating `tinytex` via `R`?

Comment: Yes but the documentation says that TinyTex is supposed to install missing packages on the fly.

Comment: I have the same problem to use tlmgr on Mint today. Any idea what is going on?